# How to match that these 2 values are same?

Tags: java

```
class LetsComp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 10, b = 0010;

    System.out.println(a == b);  // this gives false, even if both values in actual are same

   }
}
```

Comment: That's because they are not the same. `a` is 10, `b` is 8.

Comment: Java number literals starting with 0 mean they are octal, i.e. you couldn't use 08 or 09. If you'd write literals starting with 0x (e.g. 0x010) they would be hexa-decimal.

Answer (score 2):

In java `10` and `0010` are not the same.

`0010` is in octal equivalent to `8` (in decimal), while `10` is already in decimal format.

From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> An **octal numeral** consists of **an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 through 7** interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.